# Javascript - Putting ImageData Onto a Canvas Element - CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to take a source image and put its pixel data into a  element with a CanvasRenderingContext2D grid.

I'm writing a javascript function to work with certain pixel points of data,
but I keep getting an error from this line:

```
ctx.putImageData(sourceImage, 0, 0);
```

Here is my current javascript function that accepts a class ID of an img element as its argument:

```
function mapMyImage(sourceImageID) {

    // Declare variable for my source image
    var sourceImage = document.getElementById(sourceImageID);

    // Creates a canvas element in the HTML to hold the pixels
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    // Create a 2D rendering context for our canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // After the image has loaded, put the source image data into the
    // 2D rendering context grid
    function imgToPixelArray() {
    // In the context of the canvas, make an array of pixels
    ctx.putImageData(sourceImage, 0, 0);
    }

    // Call the above function once the source image has loaded
    sourceImage.onload = imgToPixelArray();

    // Get Access to the pixel map now stored in our 2D render
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 400, 300);
}
```

Why am I getting an error when I am trying to put my source image's pixel data into a 2D rendering context grid?

Comment: [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData) does not take an image element, it takes an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object. Perhaps you mean [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to clip a 400x300 subsection of the image and draw it into the canvas.

You don't need `.getImageData`  and `.putImageData` to accomplish that.

You can use the clipping version of `.drawImage` to do that:

```
context.drawImage(
    img,              // the image source
    0,0,              // start clipping from the source at x=0, y=0
    400,300           // clip a subsection that's 400x300 in size
    0,0               // draw that clipped subsection on the canvas at x=0,y=0
    400,300           // make the drawing 400x300 (don't scale)
)
```

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/landscape2.jpg";
function start(){
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,400,300, 0,0,400,300);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>subsection clipped to the canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
<h4>The original image</h4>
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/landscape2.jpg">
```

Comment: Great, this worked! But, is there any way for me to draw the image on the canvas without having to specify the src attribute within the javascript file? If I had the src attribute to the image in the HTML would that be enough? Also, how would I specify that I don't want to clip the image in the drawImage() function? I would like to draw the same exact image unscaled onto the canvas.

Comment: Yes, you can use an img element as the image source for canvas's `.drawImage`.  For example, to draw an img element on the canvas without scaling you can do this: `ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('myImg'),0,0);`  Good luck with your project!